# Every representation $\pi$ on a $C^{*}$-algebra $A$ induces a faithful representation on $A/\operatorname{Ker}\pi$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra. In what follows, a representation $\pi$ on $A$ is a $*$-homomorphism $\pi: A \to \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$, the Banach space of bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$.

From the definition of a representation, it follows that every representation is continuous and $\|\pi(a)\|\le \|a\|$. Hence, $\pi(A)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$, from where it follows that it is a $C^{*}$-subalgebra of $\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$.

It is also easy to prove that $\operatorname{ker}\pi = \pi^{-1}(\{0\})$ is an ideal of $A$. Thus, one can consider the quotient algebra $A/\operatorname{ker}\pi$. Let $p$ be the canonical projection $p: A \to A/\operatorname{ker}\pi$.

In [Bratteli & Robinson's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-02520-8), it is stated that every representation $\pi$ on $A$ induces a new faithful representation on $A/\operatorname{ker}\pi$.

From the above analysis, I suppose this faithful representation is to be defined by $\tilde{\pi}: A/\operatorname{ker}\pi \to \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$, with $\tilde{\pi} = \pi \circ p^{-1}$.

Is the analysis correct?

Comment: The map $p$ is injective exactly if $ker(\pi)=0$, so the expression $\tilde{\pi}=\pi \circ p^{-1}$ does not make sense if $ker(\pi) \neq 0$. If you replace it by $\tilde{\pi} \circ p = \pi$, then everything is fine.

Comment: @worldreporter I see. So this is the point: I actually have to prove that there exists some $\tilde{\pi}$ satisfying $\tilde{\pi}\circ p = \pi$. Is it just a natural consequence of the First Isomorphism Theorem of linear algebra?

Comment: Yeah, the isomorphism theorem implies that the map $\tilde{\pi}$ exists and that it is well-defined. You also have to check that it is multiplicative and that it preserves the star, but both statements follow easily

Comment: @worldreporter very nice. I believe things are more clear now. Thanks!